# Difference between samtools mark duplicates and samtools remove duplicates?

Tags: sequence-alignment, ngs, samtools

What is difference between samtools mark duplicates and remove duplicates ?  Is it necessary to mark duplicates before removing duplicates with samtools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`samtools rmdup` and `samtools markdup -r` do the same thing. Without the `-r` flag `samtools markdup` only flags the duplicates.

You'll have to run `samtools fixmate -m` and sort the output to add ms and MC tags to prepare the file for `markdup`..

According to the current [documentation](http://www.htslib.org/doc/samtools.html), `rmdup` is obsolete. Please do not use `rmdup`.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** just use `markdup`.

`rmdup` removes duplicates from BAM, while `markdup`, like Picard's `MarkDuplicates`, marks duplicates by default without hard removal – the latter is usually the desired behavior. In addition, `markdup` implements a better algorithm that takes care of more corner cases and gives more consistent results.

PS: to emphasize – I see no point to use `samtools rmdup` nowadays. It has been declared obsolete as @kohlkopf said.